# How to build a hanging table with CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I’m trying to build a hanging table-like view using Flexbox. It’s data-driven and in a pop-up modal, and I’d like it to be responsive. What I want to do is pretty easy to do with a `<table>`, but that’s not going to produce the ability to reshape this in the future if I need to do so.

What I’m trying to build is like this:

```
┌────────┬──────┬────────────┐
│        │      │            │
│  2020  │  Q4  │  December  │
│        │      │  November  │
│        │      │  October   │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q3  │  September │
│        │      │  August    │
│        │      │  July      │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q2  │  June      │
│        │      │  May       │
│        │      │  April     │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q1  │  March     │
│        │      │  February  │
│        │      │  January   │
│        │      │            │
├────────┼──────┼────────────┤
│        │      │            │
│  2019  │  Q4  │  December  │
│        │      │  November  │
│        │      │  October   │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q3  │  September │
│        │      │  August    │
│        │      │  July      │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q2  │  June      │
│        │      │  May       │
│        │      │  April     │
│        │      │            │
│        │  Q1  │  March     │
│        │      │  February  │
│        │      │  January   │
│        │      │            │
└────────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

Alternatively, but less usefully, it can be like this:

```
┌─────────┬──────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│         │      │                                │
│  2020   │  Q4  │  October  November  December   │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q3  │  July     August    September  │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q2  │  April    May       June       │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q1  │  January  February  March      │
│         │      │                                │
├─────────┼──────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│         │      │                                │
│  2019   │  Q4  │  October  November  December   │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q3  │  July     August    September  │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q2  │  April    May       June       │
│         │      │                                │
│         │  Q1  │  January  February  March      │
│         │      │                                │
└─────────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

Each of the labels will actually be a `<button>`.

I’ve built a `<table>` version of what I’m after as an example (first code example below), and I have a current best effort with Flexbox (second code example below), which isn’t balancing the three columns, but is otherwise close to what I want.

EDIT: As requested, I’ve mode the code in-line.

`<table>` example showing the structure I want:

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

td {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: top;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <button>2020</button>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q4</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>January</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>December</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>November</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q3</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>October</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>September</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>August</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q2</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>July</button></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>June</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>May</button>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>April</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>March</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>February</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <button>2019</button>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q4</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>January</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>December</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>November</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q3</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>October</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>September</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>August</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q2</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>July</button></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>June</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>May</button>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>April</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>March</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>February</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <button>2018</button>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q4</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>January</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>December</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>November</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q3</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>October</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>September</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>August</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q2</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>July</button></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>June</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>May</button>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>April</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>March</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>February</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <button>2017</button>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q4</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>January</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>December</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>November</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q3</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>October</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>September</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>August</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q2</button>
      </td>
      <td><button>July</button></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>June</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>May</button>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <button>Q1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>April</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>March</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>February</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Current best effort with Flexbox:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.year {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.quarter {
  flex-grow: 2;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.month {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container rows">
    <div class="year">
      <button>2020</button>
      <div class="rows">
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q4</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>January</button>
            <button>December</button>
            <button>November</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q3</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>October</button>
            <button>September</button>
            <button>August</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q2</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>July</button>
            <button>June</button>
            <button>May</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q1</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>April</button>
            <button>March</button>
            <button>February</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">
      <button>2019</button>
      <div class="rows">
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q4</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>January</button>
            <button>December</button>
            <button>November</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q3</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>October</button>
            <button>September</button>
            <button>August</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q2</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>July</button>
            <button>June</button>
            <button>May</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q1</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>April</button>
            <button>March</button>
            <button>February</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">
      <button>2018</button>
      <div class="rows">
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q4</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>January</button>
            <button>December</button>
            <button>November</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q3</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>October</button>
            <button>September</button>
            <button>August</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q2</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>July</button>
            <button>June</button>
            <button>May</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q1</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>April</button>
            <button>March</button>
            <button>February</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">
      <button>2017</button>
      <div class="rows">
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q4</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>January</button>
            <button>December</button>
            <button>November</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q3</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>October</button>
            <button>September</button>
            <button>August</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q2</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>July</button>
            <button>June</button>
            <button>May</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
          <button>Q1</button>
          <div class="month rows">
            <button>April</button>
            <button>March</button>
            <button>February</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex can do this by itself but not efficiently.

Grid can provide a clean, simple and light solution. Flex can help a little.

The code below meets your requirements for adaptability and maintenance.

```css
.container {}

.year {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 50vh; /* demo */
  width: 50vw;  /* demo */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: start;
}

.rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.quarter {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.month {}
```

```html
<div class="container rows">
  <div class="year">
    <button>2020</button>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="quarter">
        <button>Q4</button>
        <div class="month rows">
          <button>January</button>
          <button>December</button>
          <button>November</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter">
        <button>Q3</button>
        <div class="month rows">
          <button>October</button>
          <button>September</button>
          <button>August</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter">
        <button>Q2</button>
        <div class="month rows">
          <button>July</button>
          <button>June</button>
          <button>May</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter">
        <button>Q1</button>
        <div class="month rows">
          <button>April</button>
          <button>March</button>
          <button>February</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/aolman5588/pen/ZEQpQNQ?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks. I’m hoping to see if there’s a pure flexbox solution, but this is a good answer.

Comment: This is going to work for me and it looks pretty good. As I noted before, a pure flexbox solution would be _nice_ with this, but the structure here has let me build out the content dynamically with Vue.js and not lose any of the expected formatting.